# How can I prevent R from loading a package?

Tags: r, package

I am using the multicore package in R for parallelizing my code. However, if the tcltk package is loaded, forking processes with the multicore package will cause R to hang indefinitely. So I want to prevent tcltk from ever loading. I want an immediate error if any package tries to load it as a dependency. Is this possible?

Alternatively, can I *unload* a package after it has been loaded?

Comment: You could perhaps have a separate directory with packages sans tcltk. R can't load something that isn't there.

Comment: I believe tcltk is a builtin package. I suppose I could compile R without tcltk support, but that seems a bit extreme.

Comment: Also extreme (but perhaps preferable??) would be to create a dummy package, also named `tcltk`, and place it in the separate directory. Then, as long as your `libPaths` is set to look first in that directory, it'll always load the dummy package.  You could then also use set the following so that an error is thrown whenever a package tries to load `tcltk`: `setHook(hookName = packageEvent("tcltk", "onLoad"),
        value =  function(...) stop("Warning: tried to load tcltk"))`. (Note that the package will still be loaded, despite the error). Seems like there must be a cleaner solution, though.

Comment: For what it's worth, I was able to fix my specific problem by doing `options(gsubfn.engine = "R")`, which prevents gsubfn from loading tcl. gsubfn was being loaded as a dependency of another package, and gsubfn was in turn loading tcl purely to use its regex engine. The above code tells gsubfn to use R's own regex engine instead.

Answer (score 3):

If **immediately** detaching the package after it's been attached is a good enough solution, then try something like the following:

```
setHook(hookName = packageEvent("tcltk", "attach"),
        value =  function(...) detach(package:tcltk))

# Try it out
library(tcltk)
# Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done
# Error in as.environment(pos) : invalid 'pos' argument
search()
# [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices"
# [4] "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"  
# [7] "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

If (as seems likely) the very act of loading & attaching the package is causing the problem, you might also pursue a strategy like the one sketched out in the comments to your question. Namely:

1. Create a harmless dummy package, also named **tcltk**
2. Place it in a directory named, e.g., `"C:/R/Library/dummy/"`.
3. Before running any other commands, prepend that directory to `.libPaths` by executing `.libPaths(c("C:/R/Library/dummy/", .libPaths()))`.

Then, if any package attempts to load **tcltk**, it will first look for packages in `"C:/R/Library/dummy/"`, and, finding one of that name, will load it for a moment (before it's immediately detached by the hook described above).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to avoid loading a particular package as a dependency is, based on the assumption that none of the functions you require depend on that package, would be to reference the functions you need using their namespace:

```
lattice::xyplot(1~1)
```

This way, you don't need to load the package with your function, and you don't inadvertently load the problem package.