# mclapply but not lapply stops R

Tags: r, ubuntu, parallel-processing

I need to do parallel processing on an Intel i7 (8 cores) and use Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) with R2.15.0 (from RStudio). I have done this successfully for some weeks, but starting yesterday any attempt of parallel R-processing slows down the processing so it is almost dead. The computer itself is as fast as ever (web browsing etc.) but R just waits and waits. I usually update Ubuntu (Update Manager) every day, but not sure if that is relevant here.

This code stops my R from working. PLEASE DO NOT RUN IT UNLESS YOU ARE OK WITH CRASHING R, AND KNOW HOW TO USE "KILL -9"...

```
library(parallel)
library(gsubfn)

doSomething <- function(xx) {
  test <- 16
  return(test)
}

in.list <- list(1, 2, 3)

out.list.1 <- lapply(in.list, doSomething)                # Works well (< 1s)
out.list.2 <- mclapply(in.list, doSomething)              # Takes tens of minutes
out.list.3 <- mclapply(in.list, doSomething, mc.cores=1)  # Works well (< 1s)
out.list.4 <- mclapply(in.list, doSomething, mc.cores=2)  # Takes tens of minutes
```

After a lot of testing and "kill -9", I think I have isolated the problem to "library(gsubfn)". It automatically loads "Loading required package: proto
Loading required namespace: tcltk
Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done"

I need the gsubfn-package, so it is not an option to exclude it. Can anything be done to avoid this issue?

Thanks to everyone contributing to the R-tag!

/Chris

Comment: `mclapply` originates in the `multicore` package. In the past (at least), `Rstudio` has not supported `multicore` [see here](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/82-multicore-package-calls-within-rstudio). What happens if you run this script outside `Rstudio?`

Comment: The problem also occurs outside RStudio.

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
options(gsubfn.engine = "R")
```

This will prevent gsubfn from loading tcl, which can cause problems with the mclapply function. See:
[How can I prevent R from loading a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999201/how-can-i-prevent-r-from-loading-a-package)

And:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-hpc/2009-August/000324.html

Answer (score 1):

This code all works perfectly and instantly for me.  I'm running R 3.0.2 under Fedora 20 using an older machine than yours.  Perhaps you should update your R installation and try again.

As the previous comment suggested, always run parallel code from terminal R.  I do a lot of mclapply work and it seldom or never works within RStudio.