# Selectively prevent R from loading a particular namespace

Tags: r, namespaces

Suppose I want to check a function works identically whether a particular package is available or not:

```
mytrimws <- function(x) {
  if (requireNamespace("stringi", quietly = TRUE)) {
    stringi::stri_trim_both(x)
  } else {
    trimws(x)
  }
}

my_string <- paste0(intToUtf8(5760L), "abc")
stopifnot(mytrimws(my_string) == "abc")
# yet stopifnot(trimws(my_string) == "abc")
```

What ways are available to prevent R from loading `stringi` in this example, say by providing a environment variable or global option? I know I can:

1. Uninstall `stringi` and retry.
2. Modify `mytrimws` to include a deliberate switch. For example,

```r
mytrimws <- function(x, use_stringi = TRUE) {
    if (use_stringi && requireNamespace("stringi", quietly = TRUE)) {
        stringi::stri_trim_both(x)
    } else {
        trimws(x)
    }
}
```

The problem with `1` is partly that it's quite drastic, but more importantly it prevents tests of both branches in a common session. In particular, it makes measuring code coverage difficult.

A problem with the second is that it requires me to judiciously duplicate all relevant tests. For example, I might remember to test `mytrimws(" abc", use_stringi = FALSE)` but forget `mytrimws(my_string, use_stringi = FALSE)` and give a false sense of coverage.

Another problem with the second option is that I may not be the author of the function I'd like to check, or otherwise prefer not to modify its source code.

The question: [How can I prevent R from loading a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999201/how-can-i-prevent-r-from-loading-a-package) is similar but the answer is to set a hook. As I understand, applied to my example, that solution would ensure `stringi` is never loaded, which causes the same problem but in reverse.

As an example, I'd like the following to give an error:

```r
mytrimws <- function(x) {
  if (requireNamespace("stringi", quietly = TRUE)) {
    stringi::stri_trim_both(x)
  } else {
    trimws(x)
  }
}

my_string <- paste0(intToUtf8(5760L), "abc")
stopifnot(mytrimws(my_string) == "abc")

Sys.setenv("FORCE_UNLOAD_STRINGI" = TRUE)
stopifnot(mytrimws(my_string) == "abc") # now errors
```

Comment: I'm confused by the question, which may mean it's over my head. You can test for the availability of a package (just ask if it's there... see the answer below), or not load it (just don't load it?). And obviously putting a branching structure together is within your skill set... can you explain your desired behavior more simply, with a reproducible example?

Comment: Sorry it's unclear. In a sentence, I'd like to test how a function like the first `mytrimws` would behave if `stringi` were uninstalled, without uninstalling `stringi`.

Comment: If it's just for testing, you can temporarily redefine `requireNamespace` with `testthat::with_mock`: `testthat::with_mock(requireNamespace = function(...) FALSE, stopifnot(mytrimws(my_string) == "abc"))`

Comment: Very nice @alistaire also means I can cherry-pick particular packages, e.g. `with_mock(requireNamespace = function(x) switch(x, stringi = FALSE, other = TRUE))`